# php facebook login + curl + proxy

Tags: php, facebook, curl, proxy

i am using a curl script to login in for facebook

```
function cURL($url, $header=NULL, $cookie=NULL, $p=NULL) {

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    if ($p) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $p);
    }
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($result) {

        return $result;

    } else {

            return curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
}

// use of that function 

$cookie="";

$a = cURL("https://login.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1",true,null,"email=$EMAIL&pass=$PASSWORD");

preg_match('%Set-Cookie: ([^;]+);%',$a,$b);

$c = cURL("https://login.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1",true,$b[1],"email=$EMAIL&pass=$PASSWORD");

preg_match_all('%Set-Cookie: ([^;]+);%',$c,$d);

for($i=0;$i<count($d[0]);$i++) {

   $cookie .= $d[1][$i].";

}

$userContent=cURL("http://www.facebook.com/ads/adboard/",null,$cookie,null);
```

I want it to do it with proxy with curl Please let me know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess CURLOPT_PROXY is what you want?

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, ... )
```

http://php.net/curl_setopt

Comment: $proxy = "66.40.4.132:8080"; //<-optional proxy IP



 if($proxy){

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "$proxy"); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20); 

}

i have added this but no result showing now

Comment: wonk a donk.  some people respond without thought.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function curl_grab_page($site,$data,$proxy,$proxystatus){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
if ($proxystatus == 'on') {
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
}
```

use this function it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

use this function

```
function curl_login($url,$data,$proxy,$proxystatus){
$fp = fopen("cookie.txt", "w");
fclose($fp);
$login = curl_init();
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 
5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
if ($proxystatus == 'on') {
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, TRUE);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
}
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
ob_start(); // prevent any output
return curl_exec ($login); // execute the curl command
ob_end_clean(); // stop preventing output
curl_close ($login);
unset($login);
}
```

make sure you are using live http header plugins for firefox to get the right data array :)

Comment: Thanks for your help but i need to do  facebook login with curl with proxy.

Comment: i am using your function like this .. is this the right way?
`$a = curl_login("https://login.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1","email=$EMAIL&pass=$PASSWORD","128.114.63.15:3128","on"); `